# Glew does not init

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glew

I am using the following code to check for any error:

```
glfwInit();
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

I am using the non static version of Glew and I have included the .dll file in the Debug folder. I am using Visual Studio Community 2013. All other solutions suggested to set glewExperimental to GL_True or check the error checking, but I have done that and it is still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a GL context just by `glfwInit()`, so GLEW has nothing to work on. You must create a GL context and make it current to the thread, which for GLFW implies creating a window.